# Object comparison for Hangman game in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Goal: Output the same number of blank divs as letters in the word. Compare two array of objects against each other and display the common letters in the appropriate locations. When another letter is added to the array of objects, keep all prior letters in the word showing.

Issue: Comparing the two objects against each other and displaying only the common letters.

```
word: [
{id: 0, val: "w"}
{id: 1, val: "o"}
{id: 2, val: "r"}
{id: 3, val: "d"}
{id: 4, val: "d"}
]
```

```
goodAttempts: [
{id: 3, val: "d"}
{id: 4, val: "d"}
]
```

Below is code used to capture the key press and assign it to state. The state for goodAttempts and word (captured and assigned elsewhere) are passed to the component as props.

```
 handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        let match = [];
        let repeat = false;
        let letterIndex= [];
        let correct = false;
        
        // Validate if the key pressed is recurring in allAttempts
        this.state.allAttempts.map((value, index) => {
            if( this.state.allAttempts[index] === event.key ) {
                return repeat = true;
            }
        })

        // Validate if key pressed matches the word
        this.state.word.map((value, index) => {   
            if( this.state.word[index].val === event.key ) {
                letterIndex.push(index);
                match.push(this.state.word[index]);
                correct = true;
                return
            } 
        })

        // if repeat is false set allAttempts and repeat. else set repeat to true
        if( !repeat ) {
            this.setState({
                allAttempts: this.state.allAttempts.concat(event.key),
                goodAttempts: this.state.goodAttempts.concat(match),
                repeat: false,
                letterIndex: this.state.letterIndex.concat(letterIndex),
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                repeat: true,
            })
        }
    }
```

Below is the sudo code for what I want to accomplish

```
    const mapAll = props.word.map((value, index) => 
    
        <div 
            className="card bg-primary letter-card"
            key={value.id}
        >
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5
                    id={index} 
                    className="card-title letter-card"
                >
                    {where props.goodAttempts === props.word (
                        {props.goodAttempts} // (the correct letter will display in order)
                    ) : (
                        BLANK // (no text will display)
                    )}
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    );
```

I would like to keep the letter off the page until it is guessed and would like to avoid directly manipulating the HTML from the script.
[Repo](https://github.com/justin-barfield/hangman)

Comment: Seem quite complex way of doing it.  Could you not have a found:true|false prop in the word's letter array?  const word = [ { idx:0, letter:'w', found:false }, {idx:1, letter:'o', found:true} ... ]

Comment: still keep all attempts in an array for display purposes

Comment: you could also use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionWith to get intersection of letters matching guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. big caveat, untested, just typed in here as example.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           word: this.buildWordModel("word"),
           attempts : []
        }

 buildWordModel(word) {
        return word.map((char, idx) => {
           return { idx: idx, character: char, found:false};
        });
 }

 handleKeyDown = (event) => {

        const foundLetter = this.state.word.find(letter=> letter.character == event.key);
        
        // you can change condition and return found letter index if you want 
        // player to guess all occurances of each letter
        // for example, you could use findIndex above where found==false
        // the use the index to mod the array

        this.setState({
            word: this.state.word.map(letter=> (letter.character=== foundLetter.character? Object.assign({}, letter, { found:true }) : letter)),
            attempts: this.state.attempts.concat( { character: event.key, successful: !!foundLetter})
        });            
 }

 // then it's easy...

 renderWord() {
     return this.state.word.map(letter=> <div id={letter.idx} className={letter.found?"found":""}>{letter.character}</div>);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sambomartin for providing the inspiration for the fix in his comment to simplify it!

The key was to keep everything in one state and passing it all to the component. By adding `found: bool` to the object it was easy to use in a conditional statement by the component. The final object looked like:

```
this.state.word: [
0: {found: false, val: "w", id: 0}
1: {found: false, val: "o", id: 1}
2: {found: false, val: "r", id: 2}
3: {found: true, val: "d", id: 3}
4: {found: true, val: "d", id: 4
]
```

On key press I validate if the key matches the `val` of the object and assign the `found: true`. Once complete it pushes to the state and updates everything. That state is then pushed to the component for rendering the new information.

```
 handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        let match = [...this.state.word];
        let repeat = false;
        let letterIndex= [];
        let correct = false;
        
        // Validate if the key pressed is recurring in allAttempts
        this.state.allAttempts.map((value, index) => {

            if( this.state.allAttempts[index] === event.key ) {
                return repeat = true;
            }

        })

        // Validate if key pressed matches the word
        this.state.word.map((value, index) => {

            console.log(value)

            // console.log(this.state.word[0].val)
            
            if( this.state.word[index].val === event.key ) {

                match[index] = {...match[index], found: true}                
                letterIndex.push(index);
                correct = true;

            }           
        })

        // if repeat is false set allAttempts and repeat. else set repeat to true
        if( !repeat ) {

            this.setState({
                allAttempts: this.state.allAttempts.concat(event.key),
                word: match,
                repeat: false,
                letterIndex: this.state.letterIndex.concat(letterIndex),
            });
            
        } else {

            this.setState({
                repeat: true,
            })

        }
    }
```

```
const mapAll = props.word.map((value, index) =>
    
        <div 
            className="card bg-primary letter-card"
            key={value.id}
        >
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5
                    id={index} 
                    className="card-title letter-card"
                >
                    { props.word[index].found ? (
                        
                        <h6>{props.word[index].val}</h6>
                    ): (<></>)}
          
                    
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    );
```